# How to create UIScrollview inside UIScrollview programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uiscrollview, ios7

Please tell me how to set scrollview inside a scrollview like nested process.

The following code works partially.

```
int x=10;
int y=10;


for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];
    scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50,50);
    y=y+95;
}
```

Now all I can see are 3 scrollviews and the others are hidden. How can I create main scroll to view so that the child scrollViews are not hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an initial scrollView that you then put these scrollViews in.

```
UIScrollView * mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50, (y + 95) * 5);
// further configure
[self.view addSubview: mainScrollView];
```

Then change

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

To

```
[mainScrollView addSubview: scrollView];
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy it helped.  Can you mark it as the correct answer by pressing the check mark so others know that it is the one that worked?

Comment: Anytime! Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
//I have created Two Scroll view programmatically this way
UIScrollView *scrollViewOuter = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 600.0f, 600.0f)];
scrollViewOuter.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
scrollViewOuter.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0f, 2000.0f);

UIScrollView *scrollViewInner = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
scrollViewInner.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
scrollViewInner.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0f, 2000.0f);

[scrollViewOuter addSubview:scrollViewInner];

[self.window addSubview:scrollViewOuter];

//You can change frame and use in your own way
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a parent scrollview that is big enough to hold the 5 smaller ones, then change this line:

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

to

```
[parentScrollView addSubview:scrollview];
```